# Real time simulation in Veins

Tags: omnet++, veins

How can I make the one-step simulation time (e.g., 1 second) in veins take one second of real time?

I am trying to delay the SUMO update command in TraCI manger td seconds such that: `td = updateInterval - (ts + tv)`.

where

ts: is the real time SUMO took to simulate one-time step

tv: is the real time Veins took to simulate one-time step

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing question [aligning omnet++ clock with the system clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023609/aligning-omnet-clock-with-the-system-clock) asks a similar question and has (in my view) a workable solution as an answer.